# python : Move same images inside same folder progamtically

Tags: python-3.x, directory

Below code successfully creates all folder with same as image names. Now, I want to move images with same name inside same folder. This code creates folders but images were not moved inside folders.

```
import os
import shutil
images = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
print(images)
ids = set(i.split('_')[0] for i in images)  # set removes duplicates
for i in ids:
    os.mkdir(i)  # create subdirs
for img in images:
    target_dir = img.split('_')[0]
    shutil.move(img, target_dir)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct one. Just remove .py file

```
import os
import shutil

images = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

bad_files = set(["morph.py"])

ids = set(i.split('_')[0] for i in images)  # set removes duplicates
ids.remove("morph.py")
print(ids)
for i in ids:
    os.mkdir(i)  # create subdirs
for img in images:
    target_dir = img.split('_')[0]
    shutil.move(img, target_dir)
```